# Redis zscore zadd uri wrong score

Tags: php, redis

Im currently working on assigning groups to a special url, with their groupId as score.

create group-url:

```
     $this->cache->redis->zadd("group_route",$groupId,$groupUrl);
```

search if it is a group-url, and get the group:

```
function isCostumUrl($groupUrl) {
    $group = $this->cache->redis->zrank("group_route",$groupUrl);

    if ($group) {
        return $group;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Problem** My problem is that somehow the result-groupid is wrong.
I am searching for katt, that has id 4, but it reply with 3 wich acually belongs to group-url fisk.

[image]

how can i acually make it return the right result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is not the same with the score. The rank is zero -0- based, so in the case above rank 3 is correct for group_route katt. For example you can have different scores of your items 2, 3, 4 and 5, but the rank (or index) will always be the same. Take a look at the [Redis rank command](http://redis.io/commands/zrank)  
But [zscore](http://redis.io/commands/zscore) would work correct for you (you actually put zscore in title, but use zrank in example)